# authorization header not send when sending multipart/form-data

Tags: jwt

I am sending the JWT token with useForm body but on the express backend I don't get the authorization header, any idea why?

```
const body = new FormData();
body.append('files', {
 uri: pickerResult.fileCopyUri,
 type: pickerResult.type,
 name: pickerResult.name,
});    
  
const response = await fetch('uri', {
 Method: 'POST',
 Headers: {
 'authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
},
 Body: body,
})
```

To get the JWT on the backend